# How to create a SQL dump using sql-maven-plugin

Tags: mysql, maven, sql-maven-plugin

I use the [sql-maven-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/sql-maven-plugin/examples/execute.html) to handle the database before and after the maven tests ran. The examples are pretty straight forward in regards to dropping/ creating schema, populating.

How can I create a SQL dump of the db using this plugin?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is no way to do it with `sql-maven-plugin`. The main purpose of that plugin is to execute SQL statements . `mysql-dump` is a separate tool for creating backups. One of the possible solutions in this case is to use [exec-maven-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/)

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.1</version>
  <executions>
      <execution>
          <id>mysql-dump-create</id>
          <phase>clean</phase>
          <goals>
              <goal>exec</goal>
          </goals>
      </execution>
  </executions>
  <configuration>
      <executable>${path_to_mysqldump}</executable>
      <workingDirectory>${workdir}</workingDirectory>
      <arguments>
          <argument>--user=${user}</argument>
          <argument>--password=${password}</argument>
          <argument>--host=${host}</argument>
          <argument>--result-file=${name}</argument>
          <argument>${db}</argument>
      </arguments>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```